# Given weighted graph with several of unknown weights decide for every edge if in the MST .

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I got this question : Given weighted graph with several of unknown weights ,decide for every edge if its in MST , not in MST or we dont have enough information to decide.

I know that are few terms to decide for ever edge :

1.If the edge is the heaviest in a circle so it is not in the MST.

2.If the edge is the minimun in a cut so it is in the MST.

I tried to use prim algorithm and to use those terms but my problem if that i dont know which edge to choose in every step if there is an unknown wheighted edge in the cut.

Thanks.

Comment: If the weights are unknown, how can you possibly tell whether or not it's in a minimal weight spanning tree?

Comment: Some of the weights are unknown , not all of them. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Maybe this works: first, assume all the unknown edges have weight zero, and see which edges can be in an MST. Then, assume all the unknown edges have weight really, really big, and see which edges can be in an MST. Then think about what it means if an edge passes both tests, and what it means if it fails one or both tests.

Comment: Intresting way of thinking. so i can put 0 in the first step and infinity in the second, and check. i cant see why it should not work , going to try it. thanks .

Comment: If it works, let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer (and if it doesn't work, come back and we'll have another go at it).

Comment: Im trying to proove it ,but i stuck in the part when we cant know if an edge is in the MST or not ( not enough information) . I think maybe the condition of not enough information should be if the edge is not in the MST of the graph which the unweighted edges is not in the weight of 0.

Comment: You write "the MST", but a graph can have more than one MST. There may be some edges that are in all of them, some that are in some of them, and some that are in none of them.

Comment: The part to prove that if some edges are in none of them, so we cant know if those edges are in the MST of the original graph.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your comments. I think there may be a language barrier.